# How to create a function that shows me the rows in my categorical columns that have 0 and ows in numerical columns that are unique?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
df.columns
numerical_columns = df._get_numeric_data().columns
```

I ran the following code and searched for the columns that take in numerical values. As I have
so many columns, I would like to define a function such that I am able to separate my categorical and numerical columns and print the numerical columns which take in the value 0 and the number of unique values my categorical columns contain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple different questions here. A method for only getting a column by data type is:

```
categorical_df = df.select_dtypes(include='category')
```

The number of unique values contained can be evaluated using:

```
categorical_df.nunique()
```